# SSRS : How to give parameter values in URL Http requests?

Tags: ssrs, mdx

I created a dataset in an SSRS report and this dataset uses a parameter. Here is the request:

```
select { [Measures].[ID Distinct Count]} on COLUMNS,
non empty filter({ [DIM ANESTH].[PBM ANE NOM].[PBM ANE NOM] }, 
not InStr( [DIM ANESTH].[PBM ANE NOM].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE, 'Unknown') = 1) on ROWS
from BDD_PAT_ANESTH where ( StrToSet(@param_req, Constrained))
```

param_req is a parameter name I gave, and SSRS created a corresponding report parameter and joined both. Here are some screenshots:

[image: the parameter]
[image: in the report datas]
[image: how the parameter is filled]
[image: some default values]

All it works, but I want to call the report server via http requests (in C#), and provide with some parameter values. Usually, SSRS http URLs finish by the parameters : ...&param1=value1&param2=value2 and so on. But I don't see how I can provide with the value "[DIM ANESTH].[ID].&[3]" for example.

An other way could be to define a custom parameter whose values are integers, and to define a second parameter whose origin is the first one and whose values are some members like "[DIM ANESTH].[ID].&[3]".

Do you know how I can achieve either method (I think the first one could be easier).

thank you.

PS: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver15) about parameters but it seems to be only partially relevant.

EDIT : @McNets
I tried to follow your advice, but with no success: considering the third screenshot, the one with default values, I tried to put in my browser this url :

> http://localhost/reportService?%2fSSRS%2fReport6_tryParamFrom0&rs:Command=PDF&param_req=5

and I got this error:

> Reporting Services Error Default value or value provided for the
> report parameter 'param_req' is not a valid value.
> (rsInvalidReportParameter)

Please see : [here from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver15).
What am I missing?

Comment: MS Docs are good in this case. You cannot provide values in this form: [DIM ANESTH].[ID].&[3]. You must pass the final value.

Comment: I edited my question. I can't put "&param_req=3". Can you explain the way to achieve this task?

Comment: What is the command: `StrToText('[DIM ANESTH].[ID].&[3]' constrained)` then call it `&param_req=[DIM ANESTH].[ID].&[3]`. You should escape the '&' character

Comment: StrToMember does the job but attempting to put it in an URL failed with the same error, I used this site : https://assiste.com/Caracteres_interdits_dans_les_URLs.html.I replaced [,],<space>, and &.

Answer (score 0):

Done.
Defining a parameter 'param2' whose values are integers and captions are strings, the point is the MDX query:

```
select {[Measures].[ID Distinct Count]} on COLUMNS,
  non empty filter({[DIM ANESTH].[ID].MEMBERS  },
  [DIM ANESTH].[ID].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = @param2 ) on ROWS from BDD_PAT_ANESTH
```